# react-hook-form with 2 useFieldArray, string got split to array of object char

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am trying to use `react-hook-form` with  two `useFieldArray`

when I log the default value, it shows out normally, but it is not correct in "useFieldArray"
The string in photoFields becomes an object which spilt from the string.

[defaultValues log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49d20.png)

```
  const { register, errors, handleSubmit, formState, reset, watch, control, setValue, getValues, trigger } = useForm({
    mode: "all",
    defaultValues: activeObject,
  });

  console.log(activeObject);

  const { fields: itemsFields, append, prepend, remove, swap, move, insert } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "items",
  });

  console.log("itemsFields", itemsFields);

  const {
    fields: photoFields,
    append: photoAppend,
    remove: photoRemove,
    move: photoMove,
  } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "photo" });

  console.log("photoFields", photoFields);
```

console.log("photoFields", photoFields);

```
  {
    "0": "h",
    "1": "t",
    "2": "t",
    "3": "p",
    "4": "s",
    "5": ":",
    "6": "/",
    ...
    "180": "b",
    "id": "bb9d5f69-bebe-49e9-ab40-aefbd11111"
  }
]
```

[photoFields log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsA1o.png)

I have no idea why the string is not assign correctly, or please suggest me a solution, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily solved if your `photoFields` entry contains list of objects instead of strings. Probably now the schema looks like this:

```
const defaultValues = {
  items: [{ // your object here }],
  photo: ["https://examaple.png"]
}
```

You can fix it by putting the value inside an object

```
const defaultValues = {
  items: [{ // your object here }],
  photo: [{ value: "https://examaple.png" }]
}
```

`react-hook-form` tries to add an id for each entry on the array, which means only objects are allowed. For any primitives, you need to put them as a key inside an object

Comment: Thank you for answering this question 1 year ago. I knew your solution is correct, but that I have to refactor all my database/ reformat it before I use, then I remember I came up with a solution is to loop through the array and add its elements back to a string. XD... Anyway, this was just a fun project, and I am no longer maintaining it, but I was struggling at that moment.

Comment: @georgeCHAN I posted for anybody who has the same issue (I had the same issue). So I hope it will be helpful for others.